# Erro de referencia Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação no Android Studio e utilizando o Firebase como banco, porem depois de finalizar a estrutura do projeto quando fui testar ele acusa um erro de referencia do Android Strudio com o Firebase . Não estou conseguindo resolver o problema, será que alguém faz ideia de como solucionar.

### O erro é o seguinte:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.matheus.cond/com.example.matheus.cond.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getReference(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getReference(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
     at com.example.matheus.cond.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:51)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

### Programa:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText user_name, user_data, user_email, user_bloco,user_apto;
    TextView txt_nome,txt_data,txt_email,txt_bloco,txt_apto;
Button btn_salvar;
private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabase;
private FirebaseDatabase database;
private String userId;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//--Variaveis de cadastro de informações--
    user_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_name);
    user_data = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.user_data);
    user_email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.user_email);
    user_bloco = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.user_bloco);
    user_apto = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.user_apto);

//--Variaveis de exibição de informações--
    txt_nome =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_nome);
    txt_data =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_data);
    txt_email =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_email);
    txt_bloco = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_bloco);
    txt_apto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_apto);

//--Botões pra cadastro--
    btn_salvar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_salvar);

//Action Bar


//--FireBase--
    mFirebaseDatabase = database.getReference("Usuarios");

   database.getReference("app_title").setValue("TopazioVille");

    database.getReference("app_title").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String app_title = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(app_title);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });

 //--Salvar e atualizar os dados--
    btn_salvar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String nome = user_name.getText().toString();
            String data = user_data.getText().toString();
            String email = user_email.getText().toString();
            String bloco = user_bloco.getText().toString();
            String apto = user_apto.getText().toString();

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(userId)){
                createUsuarios(nome,data,email,bloco,apto);

            }
            else
            {
                updateUsuarios(nome,data,email,bloco,apto);
            }
        }
    });
    toggleButton();
}
    private void toggleButton(){
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(userId)){
            btn_salvar.setText("Salvar");
        }
        else
        {
            btn_salvar.setText("Atualizar");
        }
    }

private void createUsuarios(String nome, String data, String email, String bloco, String apto){
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(userId)){
        userId = mFirebaseDatabase.push().getKey();
    }

    Usuarios ususarios = new Usuarios(nome,data,email,bloco,apto);
    mFirebaseDatabase.child(userId).setValue(ususarios);

    addUsuariosChangeListener();
}

private void addUsuariosChangeListener(){
    mFirebaseDatabase.child(userId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Usuarios usuarios = dataSnapshot.getValue(Usuarios.class);

            //ver se o valor é vazio
            if(usuarios == null){
                return;
            }

            txt_nome.setText(usuarios.nome);
            txt_data.setText(usuarios.data);
            txt_email.setText(usuarios.email);
            txt_bloco.setText(usuarios.bloco);
            txt_apto.setText(usuarios.apto);

            //Limpar os campos

            txt_nome.setText("");
            txt_data.setText("");
            txt_email.setText("");
            txt_bloco.setText("");
            txt_apto.setText("");


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

private void updateUsuarios(String nome, String data, String email, String bloco, String apto){
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(nome))
        mFirebaseDatabase.child(userId).child("nome").setValue(nome);
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(nome))
        mFirebaseDatabase.child(userId).child("data").setValue(data);
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(nome))
        mFirebaseDatabase.child(userId).child("email").setValue(email);
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(nome))
        mFirebaseDatabase.child(userId).child("bloco").setValue(bloco);
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(nome))
        mFirebaseDatabase.child(userId).child("apto").setValue(apto);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resumidamente a exceção [NullPointerException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) é lançada sempre que tentar acessar um objeto de memória que não tenha sido instanciado, ou melhor inicializado, até o momento de sua chamada.

Causas comuns para geração da exceção:

- Acessar métodos de objetos que estão nulos.
- Alterar ou visualizar atributos de objetos nulos.
- Verificação de tamanho de um *array* ainda nulo
- Modificação de campos de um *array* nulo
- Lançar uma exceção como se ela fosse *throwable* ("lançável").

> [...]FirebaseDatabase.getReference(java.lang.String)' on a null object
>   reference

Observe que o erro foi lançado porque você não instanciou a classe `FirebaseDatabase` {*public class FirebaseDatabase extends Object*}. Para solucionar basta fazer desta forma:

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
mFirebaseDatabase = database.getReference("Usuarios");
```

Leia mais sobre o `FirebaseDatabase` [na documentação](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase).